# Diferença entre activity e Content

Tags: android, android-layout

Não sei se é aqui o lugar certo para isso, se não for peço orientação onde tiro esta dúvida. Estou aprendendo a desenvolver apps no Android Studio, e estou seguindo alguns tutoriais. Alguns casos tenho percebido que alguns tem apenas `activity` e outros além da `activity`também tem `content`que é o caso deste:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e neste apenas a activity

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

sempre que eu crio um projeto ele nunca gera o context. Gostaria de saber qual a diferença de ambos e a sua finalidade. e se tem necessidade de ter a context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você cria um `Basic Activity` ele cria o xml da `activity` e do `content` junto, este modelo já vem com um `FABButton` junto com o layout por isso ele cria 2 arquivos o ideal é utilizar o content para colocar outros componentes assim o funcionamento do `FABButton` não é afetado.

Caso você não queira que ele crie esse modelo sempre basta selecionar o `Empty Activity` quando for criar uma nova.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero que te ajude.

Comment: Certo Guilherme acho que entendi agora, este `FABButton`seria o botão voltar?

Comment: Não, ele é um botão circular que quando você cria o Basic Activity já vem adicionado no seu xml com o evento de click na Activity

Comment: No caso deste que aparece nesta primeira `activity` da imagem que vc postou, a `Basic Activity`?

Comment: Exatamente...!!

Answer (score 2):

Aquilo que refere são apenas nomes de arquivos de *layout*.

Um *layout* pode ser usado por uma *Activity* ou não.
Entre outros, eles são usados em Activities, Fragments, itens de ListView's ou RecyclerView's.

Um arquivo de *layout* pode também usar outros arquivos como parte integrante dele, ou seja, partes de um *layout* podem estar em outros arquivos de *layout*.

Esse é o caso(julgo eu) do primeiro exemplo que refere: o arquivo(layout) `content_primeira.xml` é usado no arquivo(layout) `activity_primeira.xml`.

A inclusão de arquivos de layout em um outro é feita com o uso da *tag* [`<include>`](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html).

Se for ver o *xml* do `activity_primeira.xml` encontrará uma linha com o conteúdo seguinte

```
<include layout="@layout/content_primeira"/>
```

Uma vantagem desta abordagem é possibilidade de um arquivo/*xml*/*layout* ser utilizado em mais de um *layout*.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação ramaral, abriu um pouco mais a mente.